# Unable to access camera in Docker container of Ubuntu

Tags: docker, opencv

I am writing a simple code of Opencv which captures images and show us. But whenever i am running it it is telling unable to access camera with this index.

I tried running my docker file with this command
docker run -ti --device /dev/video0:/dev/video0 pradyumn10/ubuntu-python3 /bin/bash
This opens camera for a second and then it closes it and gives a error "unable to display"

Comment: Please share how you started this container (Which parameters) and possibly the Dockerfile itself.

Comment: @Yaron I didnt make a docker file i just pulled a image of ubuntu and runned it and then i installed opencv in it using "apt install python3-opencv"
My code:
import cv2
cam=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
      _, frame= cam.read()
      if frame is not None:
              cv2.imshow("frame",frame)
cam.release()

Answer (score 3):

My issue was that I was running the container in privileged mode with a user other than root, i.e. with options `-u vscode --privileged --device /dev/video0:/dev/video0` (among others).  The `privileged` option caused the webcam owner and group to be `root`, however since I was running the container as `vscode` permission to access `/dev/video0` was being denied.

The solution was to not run the container in `priviledged` mode (i.e. omit the `--privileged` flag--causes the webcam owner to be `root`, but group `video`) and add the `vscode` user to the `video` group.  This was easily done in the by adding this line to my `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN usermod -aG vscode video
```

and rebuilding the container. If you must run the container in `privileged` mode you can instead `sudo chown root:video /dev/video0` once the container is running.

Answer (score 1):

Your camera is most probably a web camera and most probably mounted to the `/dev/video0` or `/dev/video{N}` - you will have to find out {N} on your host machine first.

once you get it, you can try mounting it into your docker container like this:

```
mount /dev/video0 /testvideo
docker run -it --rm --read-only -v "/testvideo:/testvideo" bash
```

after that your app in docker should try to connect to `/testvideo` instead of `/dev/video0`

P.S. i  didn't try it myself, but feels like it linux should not have any issues mounting web camera as any other device. I would give it a try, but no guarantee :)

Comment: It is giving error when i am running the second command
"docker: Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/testvideo': mkdir /testvideo: read-only file system."

Comment: yep, it's should be readonly, because you can't write into web camera, so it should be like this:
```
docker run -it --rm --read-only -v "/testvideo:/testvideo" bash
```

Comment: This answer didn't work for me. The mount command gave me the error `/dev/video0 is not a block device`  See my answer.